# Generate a Unique/Short Primary Key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I was inspired from [this](https://github.com/turbo/pg-shortkey) library to create a short primary key like youtubes

Than i found [this](https://pypi.org/project/b64uuid/) library that converts uuid in short,base64,url-safe id,my question is what approach should i take to save it in database

##### First Approach (Saving like a string primare key)

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from b64uuid import B64UUID

def create_id():
    return str(B64UUID(uuid4()))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column('id', String(200),primary_key=True, default=create_id)
    firstname = Column('firstname', String(200))
    lastname = Column('lastname', String(200))
```

##### Second Approach (Saving like UUID and then in REST API convert it  back and forth the uuid to base64)

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

class User_UUID(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_uuid"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),primary_key=True,index=True,default=uuid4)
    firstname = Column('firstname', String(200))
    lastname = Column('lastname', String(200))
```

```py
@app.get("/uuid_get_users")
def suuid_get_users():
    with session_scope() as session:
        users = session.query(User_UUID).all()
        if users != None:
            return_body = []
            for user in users:
                return_body.append(
                    {
                        "id" : str(B64UUID(user.id)),
                        "firstname" : user.firstname,
                        "lastname" : user.lastname,
                    }
                )
            return return_body


@app.get("/uuid_get_user/{id}")
def uuid_get_userr(id):
    with session_scope() as session:
        uuid = B64UUID(id).uuid
        user = session.query(User_UUID).get(uuid)
        if user != None:    
            return_body = {
                "id" : str(B64UUID(user.id)),
                "firstname" : user.firstname,
                "lastname" : user.lastname,
            }
            return return_body
```

My question is which approach is more efficient,i don't know are string primarykeys efficient,Hussein Nasser in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5mWz4vK10A) video says uuids are efficient in PostgreSQL because really are like secondary keys.I wouldn't suggest this approach in MySQL,is someone with knowledge in PostgreSQL to help me.

Comment: *Which approach is more efficient?* Why are you asking? You have already written both approaches. So now TEST them. What do your tests show?

Comment: calm down mate,well Im a beginner, i don't know really how postgres works am a beginner at this i don't know really how to test databases and this is not a easy question